# How to efficiently simplify using PowerExpand

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I am tying to simplify the following expression using `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Expand` and `PowerExpand`, `Factor`. However it is not always possible to completely simplify an expression.

```
 expr = a  + (1+b^2+b (2-(4 d^2 e)/(1+d (-1+e))))^(1-n/2);
```

I am interested in simplifying this  such that it will not have a fractional form as a sum. However in this way a final fractional form is of course expected.

The desired form is the following

```
 expr = ((a)*(1+d (-1+e))^(1-n/2)  + (((1+b^2)*(1+d (-1+e))+b (2(1+d (-1+e))-4 d^2 e))^(1-n/2)) )/(1+d (-1+e))^(1-n/2);
```

where the numerator has the terms with positive powers and an overall denominator with also positive powers `(n<2)`.

**How to I use `PowerExpand` in simplifying such expression?**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get your desired form by using Simplify. Indeed,
these are your expressions:

```
expr1 = a + (1 + b^2 + b (2 - (4 d^2 e)/(1 + d (-1 + e))))^(1 - n/2);
expr2 = ((a)*(1 + d (-1 + e))^(1 - 
        n/2) + (((1 + b^2)*(1 + d (-1 + e)) + 
        b (2 (1 + d (-1 + e)) - 4 d^2 e))^(1 - n/2)))/(1 + 
     d (-1 + e))^(1 - n/2);
```

Let us count their leaves:

```
LeafCount[expr1]
LeafCount[expr2]

(*  34

     74   *)
```

Thus, from the point of view of Mma (and also from my personal) the second expression is more complex than the first.

However, if you need to get the factor `(1 + d (-1 + e))^(-1 + n/2)` out of the expression you might use the following function:

```
factor[expr_, fact_, fun1_ : Expand, fun2_ : Identity] := 
 Module[{a = fact, b = expr/fact},
  fun2[Evaluate[a]]*fun1[Evaluate[b]]];
```

as follows

```
expr3 = factor[expr1, (1 + d (-1 + e))^(1 - n/2), Expand, Expand]

(*  (1 + d (-1 + e))^(
 1 - n/2) (a (1 + d (-1 + e))^(-1 + n/2) + (1 + d (-1 + e))^(-1 + n/2) (1 + b^2 + b (2 - (4 d^2 e)/(1 + d (-1 + e))))^(1 - n/2))  *)
```

After that, I would do one additional thing:

```
expr3 /. a_^(-1 + n/2)*b_^(1 - n/2) :> (b/a)^(1 - n/2)

(*  (1 + d (-1 + e))^(
 1 - n/2) (a (1 + d (-1 + e))^(-1 + n/2) + ((
    1 + b^2 + b (2 - (4 d^2 e)/(1 + d (-1 + e))))/(1 + d (-1 + e)))^(1 - n/2))   *)
```

looking at the screen as follows:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Interesting to learn `LeafCount`.  However the final expression is not the expected one. You are right that the expected `simplification` is of the form `expr1^x / expr2^y` where any `x` and `y` are positive. Replacement seems like the only option.

Answer (score 1):

This should find the denominator (factors with a negative power) to factor out in an expression of the form `A + B/C + D/E + ...`.  The `DeleteDuplicates` would delete factors of the denominator with the same base but different exponents, but you would really want to select the correct one, which `DeleteDuplicates` is not guaranteed to do.  It does not matter in this case, because there are no duplicates.  I just leave it there in case someone in the future wants to adapt it.  I think this achieves the described goal, although the numerator is in a slightly different form than the example output.

```
Assuming[n < 2,
 With[{e = PowerExpand[expr /. p_Power :> Together /@ p]},
  (* find desired denominator *)
  With[{den = 
     Times @@
      (*(DeleteDuplicatesBy[#,First]&)@*)
      Cases[
       Union @@ Cases[
         PowerExpand[e /. p_Power :> Together /@ p], 
         HoldPattern@Times[a___] :> {a}],
       Power[b_, p_] /; Simplify[p < 0]
       ]},
   FullSimplify[ExpandAll[e/den]]*den // Simplify
   ]]
 ]
```

[image]

The first transformation of `expr` puts the powers in a form on which `PowerExpand` will operate:

```
PowerExpand[expr /. p_Power :> Together /@ p]
```

[image]

Comment: This exactly achieves the desired form. For multiple denominators with same base and different exponents, I see this is already working fine. In that case I need to just take out the highest exponent of the denominator.